# Is $\tan\theta\cos\theta=\sin\theta$ an identity?

Tags: functions, soft-question, education

A friend of mine, who is a high school teacher, called me today and asked the question above in the title. In an abstract setting, this boils down to asking whether an expression like "$f=g$" is regarded as an "identity" when one of their domains is a **proper subset** of the other, and the two functions coincide on the smaller domain. Examples of such equalities are abundant in high school mathematics exercises, e.g. $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1,\ e^{\log x}=x$ etc.. Often, the domains are not specified in the exercises.

A somewhat similar but subtly different case is when both functions are defined on the same domain but whether they are equal depends on the exact domain. For instance, $e^{x+y}\equiv e^xe^y$ for real or complex numbers but not for quaternions. Yet, for the purpose of discussion, let us focus on the aforementioned case of $f$ and $g$. For pedagogical purposes:

- Do you consider $f=g$ an "identity"? What does an identity mean?
- How to convince *high school* students that your definition is a good one?

Comment: I don’t worry about what to call it. I simply want students to understand that the two expressions are equal whenever they both make sense.

Comment: I agree with Brian M. Scott. If I had to define what an identity is (which I wouldn't like to) I'd rather say that the two expressions coincide on the intersection of their domains. It's easy to make up cases where the two domains are not comparable by set inclusion.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The question in the title comes from an actual textbook, and the answer it gives is "no". Since $\tan\theta=\sin\theta/\cos\theta$ by definition, that it becomes a non-identity after (formally) multiplying both sides by $\cos\theta$ annoys some of my friend's students. As there are several "Is this an identity?"-typed exercises in the textbook, my friend wishes to know what is the general usage of the word "identity".

Comment: I’d suggest that your friend explain that there is no firm consensus, that common mathematical usage probably leans towards the more generous interpretation (making the answer *yes* here), and take the opportunity to have the students identity each example as an identity in the stronger sense, in the weaker sense, or not at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've typically seen the term "identity" used to refer to an equation that is true wherever both sides are defined. This would include $\sin x=\tan x\cos x,$ to be sure, but it would also include $x=2x-x.$ Put another way, we say that $f=g$ is an identity iff $f$ and $g$ are identical wherever they are both defined.

Comment: my favorite identity is now $\sqrt x = \log(-x)$.

Comment: Introductory textbooks (and more than a few instructors) are notoriously sloppy about this issue.  The result is that quite a few people go on in their mathematical studies with somewhat erroneous notions of various concepts.  The matter of what it means to write an equation should probably be emphasized in courses along the way throughout the curriculum, so that students understand when a written expression is correct and when it is nonsense or meaningless.

Answer (score 11):

To be precise, a statement $f(x)=g(x)$ should always be accompanied by specifying the range of all free variables involved (in this case, presumably $x$ and only $x$ is free), e.g. "for all real $x$" or - in your example - "for all $\theta\in\mathbb R\setminus(2\mathbb Z+1)\frac\pi2$". 
On the other hand, if one works with functions, then $f=g$ *automatically* means: $f(x)=g(x)$ for *all* $x$. Even if one does not care for differences on negligible sets (e.g. sets of Lebesgue measure $0$), one *should* write "$f(x)=g(x)\text{ a.e.}$" to mention this; one *can* unambiguously use strict equality if one works with appropriate equivalence classes of functions.
It is often *understood* that an *implicit* "almost everywhere" or "whenever both sides are defined" or similar should be added. Similarly, when introducing additivity of limits, one tends to memorize only
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n,$$
but the complete statement really involves "which is to say that if the two limits on the right exist, then so does the limit on the left and its value is the sum of the two single limits" or "if two of the limits exist then so does the third and the equality holds".

So to repeat: To be careful, domain restrictions should always be explicitly stated.

Especially, an exercise definitely should be written with so much care that the domain and any exceptions are mentioned explicitly. E.g. no exercise should ask "Show that $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$", but "Show that $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$ for $x\ne1$". However, you *may* encounter "Hint: Use $e^{\ln x}=x$" without specification of domain (or in complex analysis: branch) if the hint is to be applied for a suitable situation (in which case your *answer* must include "... because $x>0$" or the like).

Comment: I DO love this answer. Not precising the domain of validity of an identity leads to stupid things like $1+2+4+\dots+2^n+\dots=-\frac{1}{2}$ (from $\displaystyle{\sum_{n\geqslant0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}}$).

Comment: how is  1 / (1 - 2) = - 1/2?

Comment: Thank you very much for writing this nice answer (I particularly like the "$f(x)=g(x)$ a.e." part). If I could accept two answers, this must be one of them.

Comment: I agree that the specification of domain can be dropped when the so-called "universe of discourse" is understood.  It would be tedious in, say, a standard calculus course to have to constantly state "for all real $ \ x \ $".  In particular situations, though, it _should_ be made clear to students when a domain is limited, such as in the example you give (which can be used to illuminate why a _limit_ can exist even when a function is undefined at a point).

Answer (score 3):

It is customary in mathematics that when it is clear from the context that the numbers we consider are real (or complex), then the exact range for which the identity holds is left implicit. There is no difference between an identity and an equation. The claim that $f(x)=g(x)$ is, in the context where it is clear that we are talking about real (or complex) numbers, the claim that for all $x\in \mathbb R$ (or $x\in \mathbb C$) for which both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined, they are equal. Having said that, it is considered good practice (especially when dealing with students) to, as in the case you mention in the question, say something like: for all $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $\tan(x)$ is defined.

As to how to convince high school students, simply agree with them on what it means to state an identity. It's a matter of convention more than anything else, so once you agree on the convention you can check the details. In any case, this is a rather moot point to discuss as it is generally considered nit-picking and unimportant.

Comment: The formula $f(x)=g(x)$ is often called an "identity" if it is claimed to hold for _all_ $x$ (in some more or less explicit domain). The expression $f(x)=g(x)$ would be called an "equation" if it is not universally true but we want to find those _exceptional_ values for $x$ where it happens to hold. $\sin x=0$ would be an equation, not an identity.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen what do you base that distinction upon? do you have any reference to support your claim?

Comment: It was based on my experience with terminology used. I checked Wikipedia articles [Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics)), [Equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)), and others. It says: _"An equation is the problem of finding values of some variables, called unknowns, for which specified equality is true. [...] There is no standard notation which distinguishes an equation from an identity or other use of the equality relation"_ Another quote: _"An identity [...] give the same result when the variables are substituted by any values"_

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat subtle. According to contemporary mathematics, two functions are identical when (1) they share the same domain and the same co-domain; (2) they act according to the same rule. Hence $\sin\theta=(\tan\theta) \cdot (\cos\theta)$ is wrong, unless you decide that $\sin$ is actually the restriction of the usual sine function to the domain of the right-hand side.

For some teachers this approach is too stiff, and they prefer to accept Cameron Buie's answer.

**Edit:** I approved the suggested modification, but I wrote $\sin = \tan \cdot \cos$ on purpose. Actually, it seems to me that "trigonometric identities" are not real identities between functions, but rather identities *up to* restricting their validity to suitable sets. But this can be done at a very elementary level: would you define $\frac{x}{x}=1$ an identity? I probably would *not*, since $\frac{x}{x}$ is already undefined at $x=0$ while $1$ is always defined. Somebody tends to say that this *is* an identity, because it is an identity on the largest set where the two sides are computable.

Comment: As an additional note, I think it is important to see that the discontinuity on the left hand side of $\tan \theta \cos \theta = \sin \theta$ is a removable one. I suppose if someone came up with an identity that was valid for all integers except zero, a discrete identity, people would be less comfortable.

Comment: @nayrb: You don’t like $$\operatorname{sgn}(n)=\frac{|n|}n\;?$$ :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But this is often the definition of sgn. Anyway, I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Siminore Yes, the mismatch between technical definition and daily usage is exactly where the difficulty lies.

Comment: @Siminore: You’ve actually seen someone define it that way? Sheesh! I was merely offering it as an example of a discrete identity valid wherever both sides are defined.

Comment: I usually define it this way, since it happens a lot when I differentiate $x \mapsto |x|$. But somebody wants to define also $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$, and this requires a particular case.

Comment: @Siminore: Interesting. I’ve always seen it defined at $0$.

Comment: You know, if we all agree that the sign of a positive number is $+1$ and the sign of a negative number is $-1$, the sign of zero is unclear. We can say that it is zero, but it is a pure convention.

Comment: In working with students in applying the identity (in the example you give), I make a point on saying "as long as $ \ x \ $ isn't zero"; I find that they understand and accept that (and presumably know to watch out for that when the issue arises).  As far as some teachers finding the formal restriction "too stiff", I'd say that it is unfortunate that many instructors underestimate the intelligence and wits of their audience (except for the "unmotivated" members, for whom little will be availing in any case).  Students making the effort to learn generally appreciate the _caveats_ offered.