# How to deal with identities in which one expression, but not the other, evaluates to "undefined" in particular instances

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I haven't touched trigonometry for awhile and whilst flicking through an old set of notes I came across the following expression:

$$\csc(x) \cdot \sec(x) \cdot \sin^2(x)$$

I'm **aware** that this can be simplified to:

$$\tan(x)$$

---

My question is that of evaluating both sides of the equation using a value like $\pi$ (assuming Radians)

$$\tan(\pi) = 0$$

wheras

$$\csc(\pi) \cdot \sec(\pi) \cdot \sin^2(\pi) = \text{undefined}$$

presumably due to the nature that $\csc(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ and $\sin(\pi) = 0$ leading to the division by $0$.

---

Rewriting the original equation as:

$$\frac {\sin(\pi) \cdot \sin(\pi)} {\sin(\pi) \cdot \cos(\pi)} = \frac {0 \times 0} {0 \times -1} = \frac{0}{0} = \text{undefined}$$

or

$$1 \times \tan(\pi) = 0$$

Is this not making the assumption that $\frac {\sin(\pi)}{\sin(\pi)} = \frac{0}{0} = 1$?

---

Is it mandatory for the algebraic simplication to occur before evaluation?

Shouldn't all values for $\frac{x}{y}$ also satisfy $\frac{x^2}{xy}$?

I feel like I'm missing something seriously fundamental. What's going on here?

Comment: The claim $\frac{x^2}{xy}=\frac{x}{y}$ is true if and only if $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. The expression $\csc x \cdot \sec x \cdot \sin^2 x$ is equal to $\tan x$ if and only if $\sin x\neq 0$ and $\cos x\neq 0$, i.e. if and only if $x\neq \frac{\pi}{2}k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$. It's not true for all $x\in\mathbb R$. E.g., you can't simplify the $0$'s in $\frac{0\cdot 1}{0\cdot 2}$ to get $\frac{1}{2}$ -- one expression is undefined and one is the number $0.5$.

Comment: Related: ["Is $\tan\theta\cos\theta=\sin\theta$ an identity?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/565335/409) and ["How is this is an identity?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494942/how-is-this-is-an-identity) (and probably more, but these I found these with a simple search for "identity undefined").

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following statement is true if the set $S$ has no limit points.

When, through the normal course of simplifying, you get an expression of the form $f(x) = g(x)$ except that $f(x)$ is undefined on a set, $S$, of points, then, if $g(x)$ is continuous, each of the discontinuities of $f(x)$ at $x_i$ is a removable discontinuity and 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_i}f(x) = g(x_i)$.